# If all the statuses for each ID is complete then mark as complete, else incomplete

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking to find a solution to my query.

If each ID (can have multiple rows) status is complete, then create a new value as complete.

If one of the statuses for each respective ID is not complete, then incomplete.

Example:

**Input**

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | complete |
| 1 | complete |
| 1 | incomplete |
| 2 | complete |
| 2 | complete |
| 2 | complete |
| 3 | incomplete |
| 3 | incomplete |
| 3 | incomplete |

**Desire output**

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | incomplete |
| 2 | complete |
| 3 | incomplete |

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `MAX()` with `GROUP BY` to do it. For example:

```
select id, max(value) from t group by id
```

Result:

```
 id  max        
 --- ---------- 
 3   incomplete 
 2   complete   
 1   incomplete
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=50196a096d27515e213f11cbde2ea01e).